# Can I make the spectrum of ring, Spec(R), the topological ring or topological group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-geometry, topological-groups

Sorry for a novice question.

My intuition is that for every ring $R$ in algebraic geometry, $\text{Spec}(R)$ is a concept like a manifold.

In manifold theory, we can consider the notion of the Lie group.

Finally, I find 'The algebraic group theory' like the Lie group in manifold theory.
(is it correct intuition?)

---

My question: Is there an easier way to make $\text{Spec}(R)$ into a topological group or ring? Or is there a theory for that?

Comment: A nice coalgebra structure $R\to R\otimes R$ gives a map $Spec(R)\times Spec(R)\to Spec(R)$ making $Spec(R)$ a group.

Comment: In most cases, probably not. The spectrum is a set of ideals, and there isn't a natural ring structure on it, nor a group construct. But you might find a quotient of the spectrum that is like the class group in some instances. Don't know if that will be consistent with the topology. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_class_group

Comment: The corresponding notion would be that of a group scheme. But the spectrum itself is not the underlying set of a group (it is the set of $A$-points, where $A$ is an $R$-algebra). An example is the multiplicative group $\mathbb{G}_m$. Looking beyond affine schemes, the rational points of an elliptic curve (which is a projective scheme) form a group. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_scheme

Comment: There is a lot to say about algebraic groups and group schemes which is parallel to the theory of lie groups. For example, a projective algebraic group is commutative and is thus called an 'abelian variety', which can be seen as the parallel of the fact that compact complex lie groups are commutative. You can also let groups schemes act on other schemes, which is extremely important.

Comment: @KentaS thank you! Then how can I regard the $Spec R \times Spec R→Spec R$ as the group opearation? (I mean , is there some sufficient conditions to make above map to the group operation?)

Comment: @KentaS , also, for inverse operator, should I take the nice map $R \rightarrow R$? However, I have questions about how can I take the "nice" map.

Answer (score 2):

All the comments and answers pointing towards the theory of group schemes are what you should be looking at if you want to generalize the theory of Lie groups to the context of schemes.

But to answer your question more litteraly, it is almost never possible to give a topological group structure to the topological space $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$, because a topological group is *homogeneous*: all its points have the same topological properties (specifically, the homoeomorphism group of the underlying topological space acts transitively). But an affine scheme $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ is never homogeneous unless it is discrete, because any non-trivial irreducible component will have a generic point and some non-generic points, which are not topologically equivalent.

Comment: An affine scheme is never homogeneous unless it is zero-dimensional.  But it can be zero-dimensional without being discrete.  For instance, there exists a ring $R$ such that $\operatorname{Spec}R$ is homeomorphic to the Cantor set, which admits a topological group structure.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thank you, it is very interesting! However, I can't find that theory. May I ask you how can I take the ring $R$ so that $Spec(R)$ is homeomorphic to the Cantor set?

Comment: @EricWofsey , If R has kull dimension zero(so every prime ideal is maximal), then Can I make $Spec(R)$ the topological group?

Comment: In one sense, this answer indicates that asking "can Spec(R) be made into a topological group?" is the "wrong" question to ask. Instead, the functor-of-points view tells us group schemes are the "right" concept.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! There are several important examples of groups that are also affine schemes (the spectrum of a ring). These are called affine group-schemes, and I bet that you already know many examples of these.

One particularly nice example is the matrix group $\mathsf{GL}_n$. To define it, consider the polynomial ring $\mathbf{Z}[x_{11}, \dots, x_{nn}, t]$ with $n^2 + 1$ variables. Call $\det$ the polynomial obtained by taking the determinant of the matrix whose entries are the variables $x_{ij}$ and form the quotient ring $R = \mathbf{Z}[x_{11}, \dots, x_{nn}, t]/(t\cdot \det -1)$. Then, one can show that $\mathsf{GL}_n = \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is an affine-group scheme. (Think first about the case $n = 1$).

A great (free) reference to start learning about these is Milne's notes: https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/iAG200.pdf

More generally, you might be interested in learning about the functorial perspective of a group object in a category; of which Lie groups, affine group-schemes, topological groups, groups, algebraic groups, and more are all examples.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_object#:~:text=In%20category%20theory%2C%20a%20branch,the%20group%20operations%20are%20continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_object#:%7E:text=In%20category%20theory%2C%20a%20branch,the%20group%20operations%20are%20continuous).

Comment: To be clear, though, group schemes do *not* involve making the topological space $\operatorname{Spec} R$ into a topological group.

Comment: Absolutely, I interpreted the question less literarily.